# How to Break Down Stairs

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions, z-transform

I have a fraction and I want to break down stairs.

$$ F(z) = \frac{1 - 1.37 z^{-1} + 37 z^{-2}}{1 - z^{-1} + 0.6 z^{-2}} $$

I want it in form of 
$$ F(z) = A_{0} + \frac{1}{B_{1} z + \frac{1}{A_{1} + B_{2}(z)}} $$

where $A_{0}$, $A_{1}$, $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ are constants and $i$ is the order of stairs which would be bigger as much as it could be.

Is it possible to obtain this form from $F(z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the usual continued fraction development:
$$\begin {align} \frac{1 - 1.37 z^{-1} + 37 z^{-2}}{1 - z^{-1} + 0.6 z^{-2}}&=1+\frac {-.37z^{-1}+36.4z^{-2}}{1 - z^{-1} + 0.6 z^{-2}}\\
&=1+\frac 1{\frac {1 - z^{-1} + 0.6 z^{-2}}{-.37z^{-1}+36.4z^{-2}}}
\\&=1+\frac1{z\frac {1 - z^{-1} + 0.6 z^{-2}}{-.37+36.4z^{-1}}}\\&=
1+\frac1{\frac {-1}{0.37}z(1+\frac{12.468z^{-1}+0.6z^{-2}}{-.37+36.4z^{-1}})} \end {align}$$
and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ross Millikan. It is perfect ((: